# How to tell my RegularExpressionValidator to allow Numbers, Letters, and Spaces only?

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I am using: `ValidationExpression="^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$"` to try and only allow letters and numbers with no symbols.

Yet when I enter a phrase into the box that includes a space, it fails to validate. So I'm guessing I need to explicitly allow spaces too? Example of a search that is not working:

"Summer holiday"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add the space?

```
^[0-9a-zA-Z ]+$
```

Answer (score 3):

very easy:-

`\w+[a-zA-Z\s]+$`     for Characters only

`\w+[0-9a-zA-Z\s]+$`  Alpha Numeric

Answer (score 1):

You must include in [..] spaces. Space, tabulate, etc.. have symbol \s, so you regex: `^[0-9a-zA-Z\s]+$`